# PHP Advanced Custom Fields: Show items only if assigned to page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Please bear with me. New to programming.

I’m trying to create a restaurant menu using ACF and the repeater plugin.

The screenshot below shows what I’m trying to achieve. This is the backend which already adds the data to the database.

[image]

This is my basic loop to grab the fields needed.

```
<?php while( have_rows('menus') ): the_row(); ?>

            <?php
                $item_name = get_sub_field('item_name');
                $item_price = get_sub_field('item_price');
                $item_description = get_sub_field('item_description');
                $special = get_sub_field('special');
            ?>

            <h1 class="<?php echo $special"?>>
                 <?php echo $item_name ?>...<?php echo $item_price ?>
            </h1>

            <h2><?php echo $item_description ?></h2>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

I have three templates each showing the same menu but in certain pages ‘special’ items will be shown where a class is set to be styled in CSS.

e.g

King’s Cross Page lists Dish 1 and Dish 2(special)

but

Covent Garden Page lists Dish 1 and skips Dish 2 because it’s selected to be a special for King’s Cross.

how can I skip fields not assigned to a certain template?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an example of this online anywhere? I'm struggling to get my head around what you mean.

Comment: I don't sorry. All running locally at the moment. Let me try explain again.

I have three pages. Kings Cross, Covent Garden, Shoreditch. Each page lists the same menu created using ACF plugin. When the user add s the menu items he can assign certain menu items to a page e.g Kings Cross. So if a menu item is set to be set to Shoreditch when the Kings Cross page is visited the Shoreditch menu item is not shown.

Comment: I assume you take it off from a database. or some sort of an array

Comment: Not sure I understand? The data is set in the backend. The fields above is the backend.I just need to know how to create a loop to show the menu items and skip certain menu items not assigned to the page viewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, still not sure if I fully understand this, but if I've got it right, do you need to check if the page is equal to the special field?

Something like:

```
<?php while( have_rows('menus') ) : the_row();
    $item_name = get_sub_field('item_name');
    $item_price = get_sub_field('item_price');
    $item_description = get_sub_field('item_description');
    $special = get_sub_field('special');
    ?>
    <?php if( $special == get_the_title() ) :
        ?>
        <h1 class="<?php echo $special; ?>">
             <?php echo $item_name ?>...<?php echo $item_price ?>
        </h1>
        <h2><?php echo $item_description ?></h2>
        <?php
    endif;
endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Comment: So your code and my loop above together should work fine?
So if the user created Dish1, Dish 2, Shoreditch Special, Dish 3, Dish 4, Kings Special in the backend. If the special in the template is set to show Shoreditch then Kings Special is hidden but the menu items are still shown in that order. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This code contains your loop too, I've just added an if statement that says if the special field is equal to the page name, display the dish.

Comment: and if it isn't it will still display the non-special dishes?